# Node js Adwords Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, curl, google-ads-api

I am using a Node JS server and trying to get an access token from Adwords API. To perform the POST request i use curler from npm(https://www.npmjs.org/package/curler). Here is the code sample:

```
var login = 'mymail@gmail.com';
var pass = 'mypassword';
var data = JSON.stringify({
    Email: login, 
    Passwd : pass,
    accountType: 'GOOGLE',
    service: 'adwords',
    source: 'adwordstest'
});
var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: data,
    timeout: 5000,
    connectionTimeout: 5000
};

var startDate = Date.now();
curl.request(options, function(err, res, bodyData) {
    var duration = (Date.now() - startDate);
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('statusCode: %s', res.statusCode);
        console.log('bodyData: %s', bodyData);
    }
    console.log("curler (libcurl) performed http request in %s ms. dnsTime: %s, connectTime: %s, preTransferTime: %s, startTransferTime: %s, totalTime: %s", duration, res.dnsTime, res.connectTime, res.preTransferTime, res.startTransferTime, res.totalTime);
 });
```

The response I get is

```
statusCode: 403
bodyData: Error=BadAuthentication
```

which basicly says that login information is wrong, which is not. Can't figure out whether i've chosen the wrong implementation, or just missing a header or something.

Comment: I would guess that your regular login is not enough and you need to register for an API token or some other method of authentication.

Comment: The thing is, that the same method works in php via curl, without using adwords application or developer api key

Comment: Did you ever get this working? A functional example would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to get a fresh access token: https://github.com/ErikEvenson/googleads-node-lib/blob/v0.0.17/services/adWordsService.js#L206-L241.  The access token ends up in `credentials.access_token`.

```
  self.refresh = function(done) {
    // check if current credentials haven't expired
    if (self.credentials && Date.now() < self.credentials.expires) {
      // behave like an async
      setTimeout(function() {done(null);}, 0);
      return;
    } else {
      // throw away cached client
      self.client = null;

      var qs = {
        refresh_token: self.options.ADWORDS_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        client_id: self.options.ADWORDS_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: self.options.ADWORDS_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token'
      };

      request.post(
        {
          qs: qs,
          url: self.tokenUrl
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
          self.credentials = JSON.parse(body);
          self.credentials.issued = Date.now();

          self.credentials.expires = self.credentials.issued -
            self.credentials.expires_in;

          done(error);
        }
      );

      return;
    }
  };
```